# Simulate Eqv and Imp from VBScript in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I'm implementing a VBScript dialect and want to equally support VBScript [`Eqv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//2x782syb(v=vs.85)) (logical equivalence) and [`Imp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//57eas59d(v=vs.85)) (logical implication).

When `Eqv`/`Imp` have number operands, they perform a bitwise comparison. While I may able to simulate their behavior bit-by-bit, there must be a more efficient way than that. For example, I can do `Eqv` from JavaScript like this, given two integers *x* and *y*:

```js
let bit1 = x & 1 == 0 ? (y & 1 == 0 ? 1 : 0) : y & 1 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
let r = bit1 | otherBits;
```

This way, for an Integer, I'd need to apply this for every 32 bits. Is there a way to do that with simply some of the `& | ^` operators in JavaScript?

Comment: the documentation is a bit vague, what does `1 Eqv 1` return?

Comment: @georg `1 Eqv 1` is -1 and  `0 Eqv 10` is `-11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their bits tables, `Eqv` appears to be "not xor" and `Imp` "not a or b"

```js
a = 0b0011
b = 0b0101

console.log(( ~(a^b) ).toString(2))
console.log(( ~a|b   ).toString(2))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but the bit shift cannot be part for signed integer (`0 Eqv 10` outputs -11 for example).

Comment: @Klaider: fair enough, removed